# Run workflow on 1:N related records

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have developed an entity intended for staging imported data and doing some validation, as well as an entity that will be used as a batch reference, so that I can ensure all staged records in a batch will go into the system together. How can I run a workflow on all the related child records from the batch entity form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because standard CRM Workflow steps don't support the iteration of 1:N relationships, you need to build a custom workflow activity.

Lucky for us there is already one available:

[CRM 2011 Distribute Workflow Activity](https://crm2011distributewf.codeplex.com/)

There is also a small tutorial (powerpoint format), the link is in the same page (last download link in the bottom)